# Magento Filer the data by attribute before algolia search

Tags: search, filter, attributes, algolia

Am trying to provide the Algolia search option with filter by attribute value. For example from the attached pic, need to filter the data by city attribute and then Algolia shows results results accordingly to selected attribute

[Click Here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJC0D.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the select box with searchable attribute before search input. I assume you use Algolia's Magento extension. 
If it's the case you need to put your select box into either [autocomplete.phtml file](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/design/frontend/template/autocomplete.phtml#L16-L29) (if you are using default search box selector) or to your theme's template (if you modified search box selector in Algolia settings in Magento administration).

Then if you want to do it on instant search result page you can use `searchFunction` to restrict searchable attributes:

```
var search = instantsearch({
  [...],
  searchFunction: function(helper) {
    var searchableAttribute = $('selectbox-selector').val(); // Using jQuery just for example
    helper.setQueryParameter('restrictSearchableAttributes', searchableAttribute);

    helper.search();
  }
}
```

Initialization of instantsearch you can find in [instantsearch.phtml](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/design/frontend/template/instantsearch.phtml#L59-L67) template.

If you want to update results in autocomplete menu, you will have to set the `restrictSearchableAttributes` parameter to autocomplete data source. The data sources are defined in [commonjs.phtml](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/design/frontend/template/internals/commonjs.phtml#L269-L458) file. More information of autocomplete data sources you can find in [autocomplete.js documentation](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#sources).

Example of updating [product's data source](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento/blob/master/design/frontend/template/internals/commonjs.phtml#L281-L282):

```
options.facets = ['categories.level0'];
options.numericFilters = 'visibility_search=1';
options.restrictSearchableAttributes = $('selectbox-selector').val();
```